# Integral condition for non-negative function

Tags: measure-theory

Given a $\sigma$-additive measurable space $(E, \Sigma, \mu)$ and a measurable function $f : E \to \mathbb{R}$.

I know that from $$\int_A f(x) \mu(dx) \geq 0 $$ for all $A \in \Sigma$ it follows $f \geq 0$ $\mu$-almost surly.

I wonder now, if $\mathcal{A}$ is a set of subsets from $E$ with $\sigma(\mathcal{A}) = \Sigma$ and 
$$\int_A f(x) \mu(dx) \geq 0 $$
for all $A \in \mathcal{A}$, does this then also imply that $f \geq 0$ $\mu$-almost surly. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\delta_0$ be the Dirac measure on $\mathbb{R}$ at $0$ with the standard Borel sigma-algebra $\Sigma$. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the set of all intervals not containing $0$. Then $\mathcal{A}$ generates $\Sigma$.

Consider the function $f(x) = -1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then for all sets $A \in \mathcal{A}$,

$$\int_{A} f(x) \delta_0(dx) = 0,$$

but $f$ is  clearly not non-negative almost everywhere.

Comment: almost everywhere with respect to which measure? $f$ certainly is $\geq0$ with respect to the point measure

Comment: The Dirac measure. The set for which $f \ge 0$ has measure $0$.